# Android P2P Video chat using SIPDROID

Tags: android, p2p, sip, voip, stun

My plan is, to create a instant video chat App for Android. I've found Sipdroid wich gives me the opportunity to make video and voice calls using the SIP.

The user should just open the App and be able to instantly video chat with another stranger from the pool.

Now the question is: I only need to setup a SIP-Server and create a pool of SIP-Accounts or create them on demand. Then I'm able to use Sipdroid and modify it, so it fit's my needs. 
Is this all? How about this STUN-Server thing? Am I missing something?

How many connections could take a avarage root-server? Actually it should be a lot, because the stream is transmitted using P2P.

Other suggestions to create a P2P anonymous video chat app? I've seen similar Apps. But they use FLEX. This is not what I want to do.

Comment: I am also trying to create a video chat app, can you please give some suggestions as where to start and how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are in the good direction. You will need to do the matching logic between 2 idle users and incorporate that feature into SipDroid. There may be some complexity in finding  the idle users due to all kinds of corner cases you will get. It may be similar in features as implementing presence in an [IMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Multimedia_Subsystem) system.

For STUN, it is synonym to [NAT traversal](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/NAT+and+VOIP). You may need to care about that but it depends of your network setup.

For the performance, it will vary upon server implementations and hardware you use. You will need to do your own benchmarks. I would guess you don't need to worry unless you have a few dozen concurrent users.

Comment: Well that sounds great somehow. This is a good concern about the idle users, will think about that. I know what STUN does, but isn't it covered/unnecessary using SIPDROID? Of course I know that, but I think it's going to be something like 1.000 - 10.000 Users simitaniously. My thinking was more like: does it take more recources as (let's say) a Apache or something similar? I think I'm going to give this a try. It'll be a multiclient http://chatroulette.com clone. I think it's a good way to stay at an wide ranged protocol as SIP is.

Comment: It seems covered by SipDroid. You may need some configurations on the server though. I suggest to not bother with NAT traversal unless you start experimenting connectivity problems. For performance, how is it related with Apache? Why would you need Apache?

Comment: Just saw it, STUN is implemented. No not related. How can you compare the used recources of a Apache Server to the SIP Server. Nevermind, I'll just check it out and I'll see :) Thank you anyway.